# Is it possible to modify default image name suffix?

Tags: images

So that, I tried this technique - [Modify Default Image Name Suffix](http://gwaphic.com/code/index.php?id=9) but it doesn't work as I need, I have all the images loaded, and I need to regenerate them. And what about the recovery of the images?

**EDIT -**

What I need is have the image files named as `pic-large.jpg`, pic-medium.jpg, pic-thumbnail.jpg instead of `pic-1024x700.jpg`.

I use ImageMagick engine plugin and Additional Image Sizes (zui), in order to create more sizes than the default ones.

Comment: Can you expand and clarify your question: what have you *done*, what did you *expect* to happen, and what *didn't* happen or what happened *unexpectedly*?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify image sizing/naming, and already have image thumbnails that have been generated, then you likely will need to *regenerate your thumbnails*. There are [plenty of Plugins for this purpose, in the repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=regenerate%20thumbnails&sort=).

Comment: Sure, I use ImageMagick engine for that, but what I need is rename the images, whit diferent suffix. ie.: pic-200x500.jpg must be called pic-medium.jpg

Comment: Is this what I mean: http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/image-size-as-suffix-instead-of-image-dimensions

Comment: I don't think ImageMagick is what you need. You need *WordPress* to *regenerate its own thumbnails*. See the Plugins I linked. I typically use "Regenerate Thumbnails" or "Ajax Thumbnail Regenerate".

Comment: yes you are right, I use "Additional Image Sizes (zui)" to regenerate, but none of them change the file name suffix.

Comment: I think we're talking in circles. :) I'm assuming you've *already* come up with a means to change the image naming convention, and have thus changed the names of your existing images. At *that* point, you need to regenerate thumbnails, so that WordPress knows the correct names for each intermediate image size.

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is not so good. But the 'hack' doesn't work with all sizes, only thumbnail, and also create the thumbnail size pic-'width'x'heigth'.jpg image file.