# How can i make this in the_post_thumbnail?

Tags: thumbnails, post-thumbnails

if I add this code in my theme function.php

```
add_image_size('thumb' , 130, 65, true ); // Thumb
add_image_size('max' , 610, 305, true );  // Maximum
add_image_size('min' , 270, 135, true );  // Minimum
```

…the file names of uploaded images is:

> - photo-name-130x65.jpg
> - photo-name-610x305.jpg
> - photo-name-270x135.jpg
> - photo-name.jpg

How can I rename them to the following (by default)?

> - photo-name-thumb.jpg
> - photo-name-max.jpg
> - photo-name-min.jpg
> - photo-name.jpg

And if someone wonders why I want to do this is because: If in the future I decide to change theme, logically I might change because of the new theme the dimensions of the photos. So for what reason should I create too many dimensions when I can just replace them from the original, without taking to much space and so I won't delete the previous sizes and create 404 error in the indexing of the photos in Google.

Comment: First you should explain the "why".

Comment: I see no benefit doing this especially when trying to do this in WordPress is going to involve a lot of work. As Kaiser said; why do you want to do this?

Comment: I edited the theme and am answering your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to modify default image name suffix?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40114/is-it-possible-to-modify-default-image-name-suffix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure your image sizes remain available when switching themes, then you should place them into a plugin. Create a .php file (name it what you want) and place it in wp-content/plugins/, then paste the following:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Custom Image Sizes
Plugin URI: http://pippinsplugins.com/
Description: Images sizes to be used in all themes
Author: Pippin Williamson
Author URI: http://pippinsplugins.com
Version: 1.0
*/

add_image_size('thumb' , 130, 65, true ); // Thumb
add_image_size('max' , 610, 305, true );  // Maximum
add_image_size('min' , 270, 135, true );  // Minimum
```

Once you activate the plugin, your image sizes will be available no matter what theme is activated.

Answer (score 1):

when you change themes or adjust the media sizes you could just use the [regenerate thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to ummmm... regenerate the thumbnails to the newly defined sizes.  it may or may not delete the old ones... i couldn't say.  your approach seems like a **lot** of effort for little gain.